# How to use Gtk.Widget.set_template()

Tags: python, gtk

I am trying to use the `Gtk.Widget.set_template()` method but I am not sure how to use it *without* Gio.Resource. I am using python3 with gi.repository.

Let's say I have a foowidget.ui and then I would like to have a class:

```
class FooWidget(Gtk.Box):
    Gtk.Box.__init__(self)
    #set_template here with 'foowidget.ui'
    self.init_template()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible right now to use `set_template` with python. There is an open bug for it [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701843).

**EDIT:**
By now, it is possible to use templates with python. It looks like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk


@Gtk.Template(resource_path='/path/to/resource/window.ui')
class Window(Gtk.Window):
    __gtype_name__ = 'Window'
    button = Gtk.Template.Child()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @Gtk.Template.Callback('clicked')
    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `pygi-composite-templates` you can install via pip (or just copy to your project) that implements all of the necessary pieces to use composite templates using `PyGObject`. There is a working example project that uses `Gio.Resource` and and example that loads directly from a file too.

[Find it](https://github.com/virtuald/pygi-composite-templates) on github.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of pygi-composite-templates